# Issue related to WCF <readerQuotas> maxDepth

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service with HTTP Bindings. AppConif file maxDepth="32". This works on all machines except ONE.

My question is why doesn't this work on this machine when maxDepth="32".

When I set maxDepth="2147483647", it works on all machine.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: On the machine where maxDepth="32" doesn't work, what is the threshold value that makes it work?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried with 2147483647, haven't tried with any other values. Can you think of any reason why "32" doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maxDepth attribute is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx, and as you can see, it defines the maximum number of nested nodes in the XML structure.

I guess a client of the machine in question produces SOAP messages with a deep structure, which causes the exception.

You can turn on WCF message tracing and use the WCF Trace Viewer to inspect the offending messages, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

--larsw